# Add related object with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem that I can't solve ...
using Entity Framework, i have 2 objects :

Opérateurs :

```
public partial class Opérateurs
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Opérateurs()
    {
        Domaines = new HashSet<Domaines>();
        Contacts = new HashSet<Contacts>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int IdOpérateurs { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Adresse { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CodePostal { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Ville { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Société { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Fixe { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public Boolean isActifDansCaveAVin { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Domaines> Domaines { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

}

and Domaines :

```
public partial class Domaines
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Domaines()
    {
        Vins = new HashSet<Vins>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int idDomaine { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string NomDomaine { get; set; }

    public int idOpérateur { get; set; }

    public virtual Opérateurs Opérateurs { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Vins> Vins { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to add Opérateur (great !) but I can't add Domaines :-(

Here is my Unit Test :

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AjouterDomaine()
    {
        using (CaveAVinContext context = new CaveAVinContext())
        {
            Opérateurs operateur = context.Opérateurs.Find(500111);

            Domaines domaine = new Domaines();
            domaine.idDomaine = 5;
            domaine.Opérateurs = operateur;
            domaine.NomDomaine = "domaine Eric test";

            context.Domaines.Add(domaine);
            SaveChanges(context);
        }
    }
```

Doing this, I get an DbUpdateException (with no indication :-( )
NB : I also tried with this line in comment (domaine.idDomaine = 5;) => same result

What's wrong ?

Comment: can you debug and make sure operateur is not null? are you sure there is a matching record for 500111?

Comment: Can you share exact exception message?

Comment: @erkaner : yes there is a record for 500111, i'm sure and using debugger operateur is not null

Comment: @Kamo I can't because of DbUpdateException ! There is no Message or Source :-(

Comment: Here is my personal catching method :

Comment: foreach (var result in dbu.Entries)
                {
                    builder.AppendFormat("Type: {0} was part of the problem. ", result.Entity.GetType().Name);
                }

Comment: Result is : {A DbUpdateException was caught while saving changes. Type: Domaines was part of the problem. }

Comment: a little bit off topic... I wouldn't recommend using non-standard characters for your variable names on `C#` (á, à, ã, é, etc). It's just not a good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things wrong:

You are setting the Id field on an auto-generated field, and you maybe added in the domain twice, on lines:

```
domaine.Opérateurs = operateur;
```

and

```
context.Domaines.Add(domaine);
```

Try:

Remove: `domaine.Opérateurs = operateur;`

Add: `domaine.OpérateursId = operateur.OpérateursId;`

Keep `context.Domaines.Add(domaine);`

If that works, I will add more explanation in this answer.

Comment: Error disappear  :-)  but nothing appear in my database ... :-(